# Adding Sound in a canvas class

Tags: android

I have this class which extends a view and i wanted to add a sound in my method below. Ordinarily i add button sounds with the below method. The class is a drawable canvas, It shows me a red line but no sign of what i need to change. So how can i add sound in my method below? I am calling my view in a different activity. Thanks in advance.

```
   if(checkCorrect == goal) {
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(DrawGame.this,R.raw.button);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                score += 10;
                newGoal = true;
               }
```

Comment: is DrawGame Activity?

Comment: No it is a class i will call in another activity.

Comment: so this is your problem. DrawGame must be Context type "create(Context context, Uri uri)"

Comment: Yeah, any links on how i can do it? I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GameActivity extends Activity {

    DrawGame game = new DrawGame();
    game.setContext(this);



}


class DrawGame {
      Context context;
    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

   if(checkCorrect == goal) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.button);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            score += 10;
            newGoal = true;
           }

  }
```